# How to identify a button is clicked

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, codeigniter

I made my website by the framework CodeIgniter,

[Here is my personal website](http://www.littlecode.ymcdesign.com/)

in the first page, when I click on the "paysage" picture(on the top right), or "paysage" botton(in the menu), it goes to the "paysage" page, and then once I return to the first page, what I want is: **the "paysage" picture stay in color.**

the 'area' tag and 'li' tag go to the same page, the 'img' tag is the place where I put the color image in CSS background url.

HTML:

```
<img id="paysage" alt="page_accueil" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/cadre_vide.png') ?>" />

<area alt="paysage" shape="poly" coords="518, 81, 713, 99, 719, 232, 520, 202" href="<?php echo site_url('categories/voir/' . $paysage->id); ?>"/>

<li><a <?php if($this->uri->segment(3) == "1" && $this->uri->segment(1) == "categories"){ ?> class="active" <?php } ?> href="<?php echo site_url('categories/voir/1') ?>">Paysage</a></li>
```

CSS:

```
#paysage{
    top:0;
    opacity:0;
    padding:0;
    z-index:-1;
    position:absolute;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background:url('../../assets/img/hover-paysage.png') no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: cover; /* pour anciens Chrome et Safari */
    background-size: cover; /* version standardisée */
}
```

so I tried jQuery like this

```
$('area[alt="paysage"]').click(function(){
    $('#paysage').fadeTo('fast', 1);
});
```

of course it's not working, because the click changed the page(URL), the jQuery code can only do something in a same page.

So I understand that, I need to match:
**--if the URL is changed and then go back,

--or the area tag(or the li tag) is clicked,**
so that I can put the color image's opacity to 1.

More simpler to say, what I want is:
the "paysage" picture stays in color, once it is clicked and go to the otther page and then return, it is still and always in color.

and I'll do that for the rest of the pictures.
I hope that is clear enough, and thanks a lot for those who can help me!

Comment: I think you are referring to this css class, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:visited.

Comment: You've got a typo in your jQuery: `cilck` instead of  `click`

Comment: Ah yes, I made a stupid mistake here, thanks

Comment: I tried the ":visited" in css, the click is on the <area> tag and <li> tag, they don't support "background" and " background-image", and the images is in the <img> tag, so it's not working. But thanks for your help "chris85".

Answer (score 0):

there are 3 options.

1. Save some sort of info on server side to figure out whether someone clicked on them or not. (most likely undesirable)
2. Save data in session so you can use and access it everywhere on your site. (less undesirable than saving the info in a DB or something. Still server side though)
3. Use JS `localStorage`. This probably is the one you want

With localStorage, you can save info on client side with just plain JS and check that to see if the user has clicked the image/button or not and decide whether or not to keep the image in color.

I know W3Schools is a bad resource but it is to the point. http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: I don't exactly understand how to use this "localStorage", I'm a beginner of the web language, need more detail, else I have to give up, Still thank you so much for  your help!

Comment: `localStorage` is like session. The difference is that session lives on the server where as local storage lives on the person browsing the website's computer. Depending on whether you want to do what you need in `JS` or `PHP`.  If you click on the link above, it has some examples you can play with.

Answer (score 0):

If you're happy with localStorage / caching then this is probably what you should use.

Otherwise, Remy Sharp wrote a jQuery plugin that might be what you're looking for, provided these elements can be marked as 'visited'. https://remysharp.com/2008/02/25/visited-plugin

Here's a demo of the plugin: http://download.remysharp.com/visited.html

P.s. really like the site!

Comment: Hi, I just tried the 'visited' jQuery plugin, it's not working. I copy all the code in my js page and then      $('area[alt="paysage"]').visited(function(){
   $('#paysage').fadeTo('fast', 1);
  });   nothing happened.  But still thanks for your help and like my site.